# Given that Γ is a maximal set, show that P → ¬P ∈ Γ only if P → Q ∈ Γ

Tags: logic, set-theory

To show that P → ¬P ∈ Γ only if P → Q ∈ Γ, would I have to use soundness, completeness, or could I prove it using derivation rules?

Comment: I assume that you are mening *maximal consistent*...

Comment: No, I think he wants a formal proof of the 'principle of explosion'  That you can derive anything from a single contradiction.  Is that a reasonable interpretation?

Comment: @jobermark I'm not quite sure. This is just a question on my assignment but we only went over things such as if a set is maximal then it is consistent IFF it is satisfiable. But we did skim over contradictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** **Γ** is *maximally consistent* set, then there is a unique valuation **v** such that

> **v(ψ) = 1** for all **ψ ∈ Γ**.

Thus, if **P → ¬P ∈ Γ**, we must have **v(P → ¬P) = 1**.

This means : **v(P)=0** and thus : **v(P → Q)=1** i.e. **P → Q ∈ Γ**.

Comment: The problem has "only if", so you have to assume **P → ¬P ∈ Γ**, not the other way around.

Comment: @EliranH I thought that if "only if" was between two sentences such as "P only if Q," then it would be "If Q, then P"?

Comment: @K.Wong No, "P only if Q" is equivalent to "if P then Q". For example: "It's snowing only if it's cold" <=> "If it's snowing, then it's cold."

Comment: @EliranH Ah okay. What I have now is that..
    If P → ¬P ∈ Γ, then (P → ¬P) = 1. So, P = 0.
Case 1: P = 0, and Q can be either 0 or 1 since it won't affect the sentence being T. So, P = 0 and Q = 0 or 1, and this (P → Q) = 1.

Is this correct?